# angularjs - routing with search parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

Let's say my current location is `/phones`

I want to route to a different controller and generate a url like `/phonedetails?brand=x&size=y&price=z`

How can I set up the route and controller?

```
//partial phonelist.html

<form id="phones-form">
 <input id="brand" type="text" placeholder="brand" ng-model="phoneInfo.brand">
 <input id="size" type="text" placeholder="size" ng-model="phoneInfo.size">
 <input id="price" type="text" placeholder="price" ng-model="phoneInfo.price">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="getPhones()">Search</button>
</form>

//controller
$scope.phoneInfo = {};
$scope.getPhones() { 
  $location.search($scope.phoneInfo);
}
```

`$location.search()` generates a url like `/phones?brand=x&size=y&price=z` and doesn't transfer control to the other controller.

Maybe I am completely wrong in my understanding of routes. What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$location.search()` will only control the query string.  To change the location, you need to use `$location.path()`.

```
$scope.getPhones() { 
    $location.search($scope.phoneInfo);
    $location.path('/phonedetails');
}
```